# What protocol to choose for live audio streaming?

Tags: mobile, streaming, webrtc

I am developing an app where I can send live voice notes. It works just like Whatsapp voice notes, except that the recipient of the voice note can start playing the voice note before the author has finished sending it.

I developed a proof of concept using a webrtc media server. It works like this:

- Alice wants to send a voice note to Bob, so she sets up a webrtc connection with the server and starts streaming audio.
- The server records the audio as it receives it in file `F`.
- Bob received a notification saying Alice is streaming a voice note (she is still speaking)
- Bob opens the app, sets up a webrtc connection with the server, and the server starts streaming the file `F` in the webrtc connection.

Is there a technology more fit for this type of tasks or should I go along with what I have right now?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're buffering the voice data as a file on the server, you don't really need WebRTC. You can just stream it as regular audio data. WebRTC would be better used if you wanted to stream that audio directly to Bob instead of passing through the server first.